# Ionic Framework SQLite testing with browser

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/01/deploy-ionic-framework-app-pre-filled-sqlite-db/).

How can I test SQLite plugin and dbCopy with `ionic serve` on web browser?

I found this:

```
if(window.cordova) {
      // App syntax
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("myapp.db");
    } else {
      // Ionic serve syntax
      db = window.openDatabase("myapp.db", "1.0", "My app", -1);
    }
```

But it is just for OpenDB but not for copyDB.

My developing environment is just Netbook.

So It has no KVM and it is difficult to install android studio. So I wish to test on web browser.

Comment: The plugin to copy the database to the device uses native code and cannot be used in a web browser.  You would have to mock it by running a SQL script to populate a fresh database via your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

We recently wrote a blog article about how to do integration tests of ionic. You might want to use node express to run the ionic app you're testing as it works better on ci's such as circleci. Try have a look at http://www.dovetaildigital.io/blog/2015/10/28/rails-and-ionic-make-love-part-three and let me know if you have any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile your code using

```
>ionic build android
```

and then send the .apk file to your mobile phone.

Another option is to use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) .

PS: Does db = window.openDatabase("myapp.db", "1.0", "My app", -1); works in the browser?