# Pre populated Database with ionic serve

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm doing an Ionic Application and it relies on a pre populated database.

I can use it just fine with `ionic run android` to run on Android Emulator and it works fine, or even on a real device.

But since most of the work besides design on my app is acessing a database i want to develope and test my application without always having to rely on the Emulator, read using `ionic serve` to open the App on a browser.

It is possible to use a pre populated database with `ionic serve` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160552/ionic-framework-sqlite-testing-with-browser

Comment: @mrust seems like it [This comment explains it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160552/ionic-framework-sqlite-testing-with-browser#comment48453998_30160552) .


Must have to create a script to insert the data. But since its 17K lines in one table maybe i'll have to reduce it.

Comment: Yeah, you'll just have to mock a little less. :)